# What are the primary differences between NuoDB and MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Since NuoDB can be used as a storage engine for MySQL, what are the primary differences between using the NuoDB as a server and using MySQL as the server?

In addition, recently I've received a recommendation about this new sql database that looks intended to become a very good solution for more flexible scenarios, cloud, etc. The thing is I can't find any information about real tests or any comparison with other database systems. I'm not sure how it differs from the existing uses for MySQL and how it is different from MySQL when used as a standalone database server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NuoDB is a completely new database system written from the ground up to exploit distributed shared-nothing architectures.  NuoDB's "Emergent" architecture is the opposite of the monolithic approaches to SQL/ACID relational database systems that have dominated the last 3 decades.  In NuoDB it is the aggregate effect of many nodes that electively opt-in and contribute to the system that results in it being a SQL/ACID database.  It behaves like a flock of birds that fly in an organized fashion but without a central point of control or a single point of failure.

The product is not offered as a MySQL storage engine, partly because the MySQL storage engine API is a table-level API and does not allow the flexibility that a database system needs to do what NuoDB does.  You can see a good video overview of the product at http://www.nuodb.com/blog.

On availability and pricing:

The product is designed specifically for web scale applications, supports PHP, Ruby, Hibernate and the usual range of SQL tools/APIs, and runs either on your own hardware or on public clouds.

NuoDB is in late Beta (Beta 6 is due in the next few weeks) with about 250 customers. The product is due to ship in the Spring.

Pricing depends on whether you download it or run it on public clouds. For download it will be free forever for small installations, and will have a subscription fee as you scale out. On public clouds it will be based on the pay-per-use model of the cloud.

---

<sub>Disclaimer: I am the CEO of NuoDB Inc</sub>